# How do I combine and forwards emails into a single email in Outlook using a script?

Tags: email, outlook, gmail

I have an account where I receive about 10 daily updates/reports from different devices. Now instead of forwarding individual emails to the DL, I want to combine those 10 emails into a single email and forward that to another email. Is there a script/rule that can automate the process? I think the way it would work will be:

```
1. Between 12AM-12:30AM I would receive all the emails in the inbox
2. At 1AM, the script would run to combine all the emails in the inbox and send it to another email account
3. At 1:05AM, move all inbox emails to another folder so that inbox is empty
```

Comment: What do you mean by combine emails?  (1) Attach all 10 emails as MSG files to the new email?  (2) Merge the email bodies into a single body?  (3) Extract the bodies from the 10 emails and attach those bodies to the new email?  (4) Something else?

Comment: Will merging these emails make it easier or more difficult for the recipients to process them?  I know nothing about these emails but I would have thought 10 separate emails would be easier to process than one combined email.

Comment: The email reports are a ways of logging the configurations. So sending out 10 emails to 50 person distro is less desired then sending 1 email to that distro. While this process can be done manually, it would become tiresome to do it regularly, so thought maybe there could be a way to automate the whole process.

Comment: So these emails contain reports that can be combined.  What format are those reports?  Are they text reports that can just be strung together?  Are they tables within Html bodies that can be extracted and strung together?  Do the reports have to be separated by other text, for example, the subject of the email?  It is impossible to tell if what you want is possible unless you describe the requirement in detail.

Comment: The reports contain some texts and PDF attachments. The main thing is to combine the attachments, but even if we could attach the whole email, thats good as well. Don't need the texts from the emails only the attachments are important. All PDFs are around 400kbs, so the total attachment would size would be less than 5mb. All the report emails will be sent using a common sender. The final email just needs to have a subject like "Reports from ABC devices 05-04-2020" and sent to "abc@email.com". No special formatting or anything else is required.

Comment: You cannot move attachments from one email to another.  You would have to save the attachments to disc and then attach them to the new email.  This would not be difficult.  How would the macro recognise the source emails?  You say they all arrive between 12:00 and 12:30.  Can you guarantee that none will be late?  Can you guarantee that no other email with PDF attachments will arrive between 12:00 and 12:30?  Can the macro recognise the subject or the names of the attachments?

Comment: If the source emails cannot be recognised by the macro, you could select the source emails and then start the macro.  The macro would then create a new email, save all PDF attachments from the source emails, attach them to the new email and delete them from disc.  This might be an easy first version for the macro.

Comment: Yes, I can setup a filter that the account will only accept emails from a particular account. I saw some videos of Outlook multiple email forwarding, where the emails were forwarded as an attachment rather then the contents of the emails, so I thought maybe it was possible.  I can guarantee that all emails will arrive before 12:30AM. Is there a way we could just forward all the emails from the inbox? And after forwarding the emails move them to a different folder so inbox is empty, and repeat the process again the next night when all emails have arrived in the inbox?

Comment: I will create a routine to show you what is possible.  Its 23:00 here so I will probably not finish tonight.

Comment: Thank you Tony. Please do share it whenever you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you copy the code below to a new Outlook module.

At the top of the code are two constants that give the name of the folder holding the emails to be merged and the name of the folder to which the emails are to be moved after merging.  You must amend these constant to match the names of your folders.

The first macro is `Demo1()`.  This macro proves you have set the constants correctly by setting references to the two folders and then displaying their names.  Any problem with your constants and the code will stop.

The second macro is `Demo2()`.  This macro displays the time received and subject of each email in the source folder followed by the names of any attachments.  This allows you to check that the emails and their attachments are as you would wish.  Notes:

1. This macro displays all attachments.  Signatures, logos, images and so on are all attachments.  The real macro only forwards PDF attachments but I wanted you to know about any other attachments.
2. The items within the source folder are accessed in reverse order (`For InxI = FldrSrc.Items.Count To 1 Step -1`).  Mail items are accessed by their position within the folder.  If you move mail item 10, say, to another folder, item 11 becomes item 10, item 12 becomes item 11 and so on.  That would mean item 11 was never examined.  By accessing the items in reverse order, I do not care that item 11 has become item 10 because I have already checked item 11.

The final macro is `MergeEmailsAndForward()`.  I believe this does everything you want.  Notes:

1. Near the end of the macro is the statement `.Recipients.Add "TonyDallimore23@gmail.com"`.  For testing, I sent the merged email to one of my secondary accounts.  You will need a `.Recipients.Add "xxxx@xxxx.com"` for every individual or group who is to receive the email.
2. I have set the subject to today’s date.  You may need to adjust this.

Hope this all makes sense.

```
Option Explicit

  ' Names of folders. The first part identifies the store. Other parts
  ' identify folders to any depth of nesting.
  ' Replace with the names of your source and destination folders
  Const FldrSrcName As String = "Outlook Data File\Inbox"
  Const FldrProcName As String = "Outlook Data File\Inbox\Processed"
Sub Demo1()

  Dim FldrName As String
  Dim FldrNamePart() As String
  Dim FldrSrc As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrProc As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrTemp As Outlook.Folder
  Dim InxFN As Long

  ' Create reference to source folder
  FldrNamePart = Split(FldrSrcName, "\")
  Set FldrSrc = Session.Folders(FldrNamePart(0))
  For InxFN = 1 To UBound(FldrNamePart)
    Set FldrSrc = FldrSrc.Folders(FldrNamePart(InxFN))
  Next
  ' The above is equivalent to:
  '      Set FldrInbox = Session.Folders(Outlook Data File).Folders("Inbox")

  ' Create reference to processed folder
  FldrNamePart = Split(FldrProcName, "\")
  Set FldrProc = Session.Folders(FldrNamePart(0))
  For InxFN = 1 To UBound(FldrNamePart)
    Set FldrProc = FldrProc.Folders(FldrNamePart(InxFN))
  Next
  ' The above is equivalent to:
  '      Set FldrInbox = Session.Folders(Outlook Data File).Folders("Inbox").folders("Processed")

  ' Display name of source folder
  FldrName = FldrSrc.Name
  Set FldrTemp = FldrSrc.Parent
  Do While True
    FldrName = FldrTemp.Name & "\" & FldrName
    If TypeName(FldrTemp.Parent) = "NameSpace" Then
      Exit Do
    End If
    Set FldrTemp = FldrTemp.Parent
  Loop
  Debug.Print FldrName
  ' The above is equivalent to:
  '     Debug.Print FldrInbox.Parent.Name & "\" & FldrInbox.Name

  ' Display name of processed folder
  FldrName = FldrProc.Name
  Set FldrTemp = FldrProc.Parent
  Do While True
    FldrName = FldrTemp.Name & "\" & FldrName
    If TypeName(FldrTemp.Parent) = "NameSpace" Then
      Exit Do
    End If
    Set FldrTemp = FldrTemp.Parent
  Loop
  Debug.Print FldrName
  ' The above is equivalent to:
  '     Debug.Print FldrProc.Parent.Parent.Name & "\" & FldrProc.Parent.Name & "\" & FldrProc.Name

End Sub
Sub Demo2()

  Dim AttachCrnt As Attachment
  Dim FldrNamePart() As String
  Dim FldrSrc As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrProc As Outlook.Folder
  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxFN As Long
  Dim InxI As Long
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  FldrNamePart = Split(FldrSrcName, "\")
  Set FldrSrc = Session.Folders(FldrNamePart(0))
  For InxFN = 1 To UBound(FldrNamePart)
    Set FldrSrc = FldrSrc.Folders(FldrNamePart(InxFN))
  Next

  For InxI = FldrSrc.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set ItemCrnt = FldrSrc.Items(InxI)
    With ItemCrnt
      Debug.Print .ReceivedTime & " " & .Subject
      For InxA = 1 To ItemCrnt.Attachments.Count
        Set AttachCrnt = ItemCrnt.Attachments(InxA)
        With AttachCrnt
          Debug.Print "  " & InxA & " " & .Filename
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next

End Sub
Sub MergeEmailsAndForward()

  Dim AttachCrnt As Attachment
  Dim FldrNamePart() As String
  Dim FldrSrc As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrProc As Outlook.Folder
  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxFN As Long
  Dim InxI As Long
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim MailItemNew As MailItem
  Dim Path As String

  Path = Environ("Temp")

  ' Create reference to source folder
  FldrNamePart = Split(FldrSrcName, "\")
  Set FldrSrc = Session.Folders(FldrNamePart(0))
  For InxFN = 1 To UBound(FldrNamePart)
    Set FldrSrc = FldrSrc.Folders(FldrNamePart(InxFN))
  Next

  ' Create reference to processed folder
  FldrNamePart = Split(FldrProcName, "\")
  Set FldrProc = Session.Folders(FldrNamePart(0))
  For InxFN = 1 To UBound(FldrNamePart)
    Set FldrProc = FldrProc.Folders(FldrNamePart(InxFN))
  Next

  Set MailItemNew = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  For InxI = FldrSrc.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set ItemCrnt = FldrSrc.Items(InxI)
    With ItemCrnt
      For InxA = 1 To ItemCrnt.Attachments.Count
        Set AttachCrnt = ItemCrnt.Attachments(InxA)
        With AttachCrnt
          If LCase(Right(.Filename, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
            .SaveAsFile Path & "\" & .Filename
            MailItemNew.Attachments.Add Path & "\" & .Filename, olByValue
          End If
        End With
      Next
    End With
    ItemCrnt.Move FldrProc
  Next

  With MailItemNew
    .Recipients.Add "TonyDallimore23@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Reports from ABC devices " & Format(Now(), "d mmm yy")
    '.Display  ' Display for final checking
    '.Save     ' Save to Drafts for checking later
    .Send      ' Save to Outbox to be sent as soon as possible
  End With

End Sub
```